# React native Unable to resolve module expo-modules-core - Creative Tim Argon UI KIT

Tags: react-native, expo

I try to install https://www.creative-tim.com/product/argon-pro-react-native, a template from Creative Tim for React Native.
I follow all the steps, and when I launch Expo Go, I have this error :

> Unable to resolve module expo-modules-core from /Users/MYNAMES/Desktop/argon-pro-react-native-v1.6.0/node_modules/expo-splash-screen/build/SplashScreen.js: expo-modules-core could not be found within the project.

```
If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
```

When I check in node_modules, the file SplashScreen.js exist. But expo-modules-core, I don't know exactly where is it supposed to be ?

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "argon-pro-react-native",
  "version": "1.6.0",
  "description": "Argon Pro React Native, based on Argon Design System. Coded by Creative Tim",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/creativetimofficial/argon-pro-react-native.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/compat": "^5.1.25",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "5.12.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "5.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "5.14.3",
    "expo": "^40.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.0.1",
    "expo-asset": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-font": "~8.4.0",
    "galio-framework": "^0.7.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "git+https://github.com/siemiatj/react-native-modal-dropdown.git",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.15.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "8.3.0"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "argon react native",
    "argon design system",
    "argon app react native",
    "argon iOS",
    "react native iOS",
    "creative tim",
    "argon Android",
    "react native ui kit",
    "react native expo",
    "freebie",
    "react native argon design",
    "react native galio",
    "galio argon pro",
    "galio react native free app",
    "argon expo react native",
    "react native ui template"
  ],
  "author": "Creative Tim <hello@creative-tim.com> (https://www.creative-tim.com/)",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/creativetimofficial/ct-argon-pro-react-native/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://demos.creative-tim.com/argon-pro-react-native"
}
```

So I'm block on this error. I already try the 4 step (clear Watchman etc.)

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I've found that the issue comes from splashscreen, but I couldn't resolve it...

Comment: I installed the missing module expo-modules-core and it started working!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I reached the same error message while going through a React Native course on Udemy and it seems to be related to Expo changing the way it's modules should be installed.

Running this command on my terminal solved it:

```
expo install expo-modules-core
```

Comment: It works for me. Thank you !

Comment: First thing that worked, like a charm. Thanks!