# Error building React Native Expo project with bare workflow after switching to Expo modules

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am facing an issue while trying to build my React Native Expo project after migrating to the bare workflow. Previously, I used Expo as a manager, but now I need to install native libraries.

When attempting to install the application on my Android device using the command `npx expo run:android`, I encountered the following error:

```
npx expo run:android
› Building app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :app
 ??  Applying gradle plugin 'expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin' (expo-dev-launcher@2.4.14)

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_app
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at E:\tcc\dev\test-build-android\decide-brasil-mobile\decide-mobile\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:firebase.bom using default value: 32.7.1
:react-native-firebase_app:play.play-services-auth using default value: 20.7.0
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at E:\tcc\dev\test-build-android\decide-brasil-mobile\decide-mobile\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:version set from package.json: 18.8.0 (18,8,0 - 18008000)
:react-native-firebase_app:android.compileSdk using custom value: 33
:react-native-firebase_app:android.targetSdk using custom value: 33
:react-native-firebase_app:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_app:reactNativeAndroidDir E:\tcc\dev\test-build-android\decide-brasil-mobile\decide-mobile\node_modules\react-native\android      

> Configure project :expo

Using expo modules
  - expo-application (5.3.1)
  - expo-camera (13.4.4)
  - expo-clipboard (4.3.1)
  - expo-constants (14.4.2)
  - expo-dev-client (2.4.12)
  - expo-dev-launcher (2.4.14)
  - expo-dev-menu (3.2.2)
  - expo-document-picker (11.5.4)
  - expo-file-system (15.4.5)
  - expo-font (11.4.0)
  - expo-image-loader (4.3.0)
  - expo-image-picker (14.3.2)
  - expo-json-utils (0.7.1)
  - expo-keep-awake (12.3.0)
  - expo-manifests (0.7.2)
  - expo-media-library (15.4.1)
  - expo-modules-core (1.5.13)
  - expo-modules-core$android-annotation-processor (1.5.13)
  - expo-modules-core$android-annotation (1.5.13)
  - expo-permissions (14.2.1)
  - expo-splash-screen (0.20.5)


> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
No AAR for react-native-reanimated found. Attempting to build from source.
Android gradle plugin: 7.4.2
Gradle: 8.0.1
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

The Kotlin Gradle plugin was loaded multiple times in different subprojects, which is not supported and may break the build. 
This might happen in subprojects that apply the Kotlin plugins with the Gradle 'plugins { ... }' DSL if they specify explicit versions, even if the versions are equal.
Please add the Kotlin plugin to the common parent project or the root project, then remove the versions in the subprojects.
If the parent project does not need the plugin, add 'apply false' to the plugin line.
See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl
The Kotlin plugin was loaded in the following projects: ':expo', ':expo-modules-core', ':react-native-gesture-handler', ':react-native-safe-area-context', ...

> Task :expo-modules-core:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1429] error when building with cmake using E:\tcc\dev\test-build-android\decide-brasil-mobile\decide-mobile\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android\CMakeLists.txt: C++ build system [prefab] failed while executing:
      @echo off
      "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.14\\bin\\java" ^
        --class-path ^
        "C:\\Users\\Usußrio\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\com.google.prefab\\cli\\2.0.0\\f2702b5ca13df54e3ca92f29d6b403fb6285d8df\\cli-2.0.0-all.jar" ^
        com.google.prefab.cli.AppKt ^
        --build-system ^
        cmake ^
        --platform ^
        android ^
        --abi ^
        arm64-v8a ^
        --os-version ^
        21 ^
        --stl ^
        c++_shared ^
        --ndk-version ^
        23 ^
        --output ^
        "C:\\Users\\Usußrio\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\agp-prefab-staging11606155158266724458\\staged-cli-output" ^
        "C:\\Users\\Usußrio\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\86abc60c7c9885ad6a7513601514ac1d\\transformed\\jetified-react-android-0.72.6-debug\\prefab" ^
        "C:\\Users\\Usußrio\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-3\\48c32574c7a856298f6c15f14dd10302\\transformed\\jetified-fbjni-0.3.0\\prefab"
    from E:\tcc\dev\test-build-android\decide-brasil-mobile\decide-mobile\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android
  Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.prefab.cli.AppKt
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.prefab.cli.AppKt

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 49s
578 actionable tasks: 12 executed, 566 up-to-date
Error: E:\tcc\dev\test-build-android\decide-brasil-mobile\decide-mobile\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: E:\tcc\dev\test-build-android\decide-brasil-mobile\decide-mobile\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (E:\tcc\dev\test-build-android\decide-brasil-mobile\decide-mobile\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:52:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (E:\tcc\dev\test-build-android\decide-brasil-mobile\decide-mobile\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1093:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
    ...
    at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (E:\tcc\dev\test-build-android\decide-brasil-mobile\decide-mobile\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:17:21)
    at spawnGradleAsync (E:\tcc\dev\test-build-android\decide-brasil-mobile\decide-mobile\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:72:46)
    at Object.assembleAsync (E:\tcc\dev\test-build-android\decide-brasil-mobile\decide-mobile\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:52:18)
    at runAndroidAsync (E:\tcc\dev\test-build-android\decide-brasil-mobile\decide-mobile\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\run\android\runAndroidAsync.js:36:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

The error seems to be related to Gradle execution and CMake configuration, specifically with the `expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin` and the class `com.google.prefab.cli.AppKt`.

I have checked the documentation, but couldn't find a solution to this problem. Has anyone encountered something similar or could offer guidance on resolving this error?

**Additional Information:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.6.0",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.4",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.8.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.9",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.17.15",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "axios": "^1.6.1",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3",
    "expo-camera": "~13.4.4",
    "expo-clipboard": "~4.3.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.12",
    "expo-document-picker": "~11.5.4",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.4.5",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-media-library": "~15.4.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.49.2",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.10.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.7",
    "yup": "^1.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.1.0",
    "prettier": "^3.1.1"
  },
}
```

OS: Windows 11

I've already tried to resolve it with the information available at:[https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/22029](https://stackoverflow.com) but I haven't made any progress so far.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! o/ Have you tried updating Cmake in Android Studio? You could also try this fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70630934/react-native-unable-to-resolve-module-expo-modules-core-creative-tim-argon-ui?rq=2.

Comment: Double Check if this dep exists: ```Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.prefab.cli.AppKt
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.prefab.cli.AppKt```

Answer (score 0):

- it seems like the build is failing due to a class not found exception for com.google.prefab.cli.AppKt. This class is part of the Prefab CLI, which is used by Expo : https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/22029
- Journey to update an outdated ejected Expo React Native project : [https://medium.com/geekculture/journey-to-update-an-outdated-ejected-expo-react-native-project-9f808134bf13#:~:text=Problem:%20getting%20%E2%80%9CTask:%20expo%2Dmodules%2Dcore:configureCMakeDebug[arm64%2Dv8a]%20FAILED%E2%80%9D.%20It%20complain%20about%20fbjni%20having%20no%20compatible%20library%20with](https://medium.com/geekculture/journey-to-update-an-outdated-ejected-expo-react-native-project-9f808134bf13#:%7E:text=Problem:%20getting%20%E2%80%9CTask:%20expo%2Dmodules%2Dcore:configureCMakeDebug%5Barm64%2Dv8a%5D%20FAILED%E2%80%9D.%20It%20complain%20about%20fbjni%20having%20no%20compatible%20library%20with)
- Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]' : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74420630/execution-failed-for-task-expo-modules-corebuildcmakedebugarm64-v8a#:~:text=What%20went%20wrong:%20Execution%20failed%20for%20task%20':expo%2Dmodules%2Dcore:buildCMakeDebug[armeabi%2Dv7a]'.%20Build%20command%20failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74420630/execution-failed-for-task-expo-modules-corebuildcmakedebugarm64-v8a#:%7E:text=What%20went%20wrong:%20Execution%20failed%20for%20task%20%27:expo%2Dmodules%2Dcore:buildCMakeDebug%5Barmeabi%2Dv7a%5D%27.%20Build%20command%20failed).